# iOS automatically deleting images inside Documents Directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdwebimage

We have an Enterprise app that we have been distributing with an enterprise license.

It's an offline app in which users have to sync data and images when they are online. There are about 30k images, a total size of about 3GB which users have to download when they are online. We have used SDWebImage to download images. We have downloaded the images into Documents Directory, and we have not flagged them as not back up.

Recently, we got complaints from clients that after they have synced all images in iPad, the images are available for 2-3 days, and are automatically deleted(which can be verified from setting) after some days.

We checked and found that the images are getting deleted even if there is enough free space on the device, and nowhere in the code we have written any statement that will delete all images. It seems iOS is taking care of disk space and clearing any folder that exceeds size more than 3GB.

Has anyone come up with such situation. Are we doing wrong by saving images in Documents Directory? Should we flag them as not backed up while saving in Documents Folder, is this compulsory that is causing the issue? Should we have downloaded images in the cache directory, but in cache directory, as per the documentation, iOS deletes files when the disk space gets low.

The screenshot of documents directory as seen on iTunes has been attached.[image]

We have used SDWebManager to save image into documents directory, and here is the code.

```
 func downloadImages(_ imageUrl: String) {
        let sdManager = SDWebImageManager.shared()

        sdManager.cachedImageExists(for: URL(string: imageUrl), completion: { (exist) in
            if !exist {
                sdManager.imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), options: .lowPriority, progress: { (receivedSize, expectedSize, targetURL) in

                }, completed: { (image, data, error, finished) in
                    let imageCache = SDImageCache.shared()
                    if image != nil {
                        imageCache.store(image, forKey: imageUrl, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        })

}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, SDWebImage has default cacheAge.
```
    #import "SDImageCacheConfig.h"

    static const NSInteger kDefaultCacheMaxCacheAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 1 week
```

Comment: Thanks Tony Nguyen. Saved my day. SDWebImage should have mentioned in the documentation.